# Cannot access my webpage after setting a new user in php

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, localhost, lampp

I work on Ubuntu 12.04 with MySQL and LAMPP. I run some commands in order to make a new user and gain extra privileges for executing "chmod" and "exec" commands in PHP.

After the set up of the new user, when I try to log in to my site I get the error below:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]

Also, I cannot login to "localhost/phpmyadmin", and I see the following error:

> ## 2002 - No such file or directory The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

I tried to find a way to revoke the new user's privileges, but I found nothing.
With the "whoami" command in PHP I get the new user's name.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

For Apache:

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www -R
chmod 755 /var/www -R
addgroup your_user www-data
```

For XAMPP

```
chown vaggos:vaggos /opt/lampp -R 
chmod 755 /opt/lampp -R 
addgroup your_user vaggos
```

For temp folder:

```
chown vaggos:vaggos /temp -R 
chmod 755 /temp -R
```

OR

```
chown www-data:www-data /temp -R 
chmod 755 /temp -R
```

Check this for more detailed information: [How to fix permission of htdocs in Ubuntu](http://computernetworkingnotes.com/ubuntu-12-04-tips-and-tricks/how-to-fix-permission-of-htdocs-in-ubuntu.html)

If this answer was usefull, give +1 ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried it, run the commands with "/opt/lampp" instead of "/var/www". I still cannot enter localhost/phpmyadmin, nor my webpage. The error i get at the webpage is    "Warning: Unknown: open(/opt/lampp/temp//sess_2f1inmeaprigg0cj5mn72cge34, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)"

Comment: What is the user that your webserver uses?

Comment: run the command:  #cat /etc/shadow | grep -c www-data   (it returns 0 or 1?)

Comment: The user's name is "vaggos", the new one that i created.

Comment: run the command: #cat /etc/shadow | grep -c www-data (it returns 0 or 1?)

Comment: and this: ps aux | grep www-data

Comment: this returns "vaggos   19430  0.0  0.0  13596   936 pts/3    S+   02:42   0:00 grep --color=auto www-data"

Comment: Maybe this can be useful too: http://computernetworkingnotes.com/ubuntu-12-04-tips-and-tricks/how-to-fix-permission-of-htdocs-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: chown vaggos:vaggos /var/www -R
chmod 755 /var/www -R
addgroup your_user vaggos

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This helped and let me get through localhost. But the problem with the webpage still exists. Thank you for your time!!

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: I just solved it. The problem was with the write permissions (777) in /temp file. I gave this privileges to all the archives in temp file and now it works fine!! Now it doesn't destroys the session after I log out from the website.

Comment: Don't use 777 ... try like 755 for the webserver user.

Comment: I'll be glad if you choose my question or mark as useful. Thanks!